# Current keyboard layout not shown in Unity system tray

Tags: 20.04, unity, keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity desktop installed and two keyboard layouts added (English and Russian). However, for some reason the indicator does not show which one is selected at the current moment. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of tray showing no keyboard layout indicator]

Is there some package which Has to be installed? How can that be solved?

Comment: Maybe a bug: `ubuntu-bug unity`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, how should this help? I send a buf report this way for it to be fixed after an update?

Comment: Yes. If it is a bug, that is. I'm not sure. And if it is a bug, it's off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default icon theme (yaru) does that. `Open Unity Tweak Tool` and change icon theme to whatever exept yaru themes. I prefer the clasic Ubuntu light or dark.   Papirus Theme is very popular these days.
Have fun!